# jmeter download 1.5g file out of memory exception

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

I'M running jmx from command line

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:4096ize=4096m -XX:MaxNewSize=4096m"  && export JVM_ARGS && ./jmeter.sh -n -t ./jmeter-ec2.jmx -l ./scriptresults.jtl
```

but on some point I got out of memory error , after going to jmeter.log
I found this error

> ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_91]     at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_91]     at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_91]     at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_91]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1833)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:440)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:474)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91] 2018-01-26
>   02:03:55,731 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test
>   listeners of end of test 2018-01-26 02:03:55,732 INFO
>   o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0
>   Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)

what I"M doing wrong here ? I cant solve it:(

Comment: Your JVM_ARGS are wrong.  It this a typo, cut-paste error or you really have `-XX:4096ize=4096m` in your config?

Comment: Not much solutions to head space depletion, other than increasing your JVM size...  And-or run your JVM with GC logs and check if your running out of perm gen space, or other, that you could adjust parameters for.

Comment: so how should me line look?

Comment: Look at your JVM documentation to see which `-XX` options are available.  If they are not known, they are ignored by the JVM and no error message is trown.  For JVM tuning, see the doc on the web, a quick Google search will give you a ton of links.

Comment: So what is your question? are you asking if your arguments are working, or why memory got exhausted, even though it was 4GB?

Answer (score 1):

Your JVM arguments are wrong, just keep:

> -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m

You don't tell with how much threads this occurs nor if you're running in GUI or NON GUI mode, so:

1. Don't run in GUI mode, it's an anti-pattern
2. Ensure you have enough memory for your threads

Finally you can reduce the memory impact of big response by adapting this in user.properties:

> [httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)

And another option is to only compute HASH from your response by setting this in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request:

[image: HTTP Request Advanced panel]

Comment: its to download 1 file ! not clear why i have this issue

Comment: What did you change based on my last answer ?

Comment: I already fix my issue by correct the JVM value and check the machine really have enough memory, and I will check your answer tomorrow and if I found it helpful you will get the check mark

Answer (score 0):

Well, given you have 1.5 GB file you will be able to have not more than 3 virtual users which doesn't look like a "load test" to me.

If you are not interested in downloaded file's content and just want to stress your server you can consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which will send request and discard the response data using underlying [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) libraries methods, the relevant Groovy code would be something like:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def get = new HttpGet('http://example.com')
def response = client.execute(get)
EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity())
```

References:

- [HttpClient Tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html)
- [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I have allready solve me issue my friend , but thank you for the advice